# Updating VOIP App

Tags: ios, upgrade, voip

If I have a voip-type app that has been launched by the user and is in the background what happens when the app is upgraded? Does the app automatically restart in the background or does the user have to relaunch it to get the listening started?

Comment: You're talking about what happens when you submit an update to the App Store and the app is updated on the device from the store?

Comment: Sorry, neglected to mention that it is an enterprise app distributed via MDM

Comment: Could you explain what MDM is?